# is there a key shortcut in Eclipse to copy the whole method body into buffer?

Tags: java, eclipse

is there a key shortcut in Eclipse to copy the whole method body into buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Little know trick, use the **folding** feature:

If a method is folded, and if you select the folded line, you will actually copy the full body of said method.

[image: http://img210.i_mageshack.us/img210/7209/eclipsecopymethod.png]

If the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> does not work for large number of lines, this will.

Answer (score 8):

You can find a list of shortcuts in Eclipse by typing Ctrl+Shift+L.

While you are exploring this list, you will find Alt+Shift+Right which selects the next element. This may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> several (5-10 if you start from empty selection) times to expand selection to include the whole method body.

Comment: Well that's well known ;) If your method body contains > 100 lines it gets difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy a code block (including a method body), double click to the right of the first curly brace, the whole block will become highlighted, then it's just a Control-C, Control-V thing :)